# Как работает function () и как рисовать символами?

Tags: javascript

Ув. программисты. Я студент первого курса ХНУРЭ. Мы сейчас начали изучать Javascript. Но поскольку я раньше никогда этим не занимался, то немного отстал. Я не могу понять, как работает '`function ()`'. И как рисовать картинки символами. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 4):

Картинки символами рисовать легко.
[таблица ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/)

Использование функций - функция - это подпрограмма. Простейший вариант: Если какой-то кусок кода у вас встречается много раз, можно его один раз написать внутри функции, а потом просто вызывать эту функцию, где требуется.

Синтаксис:

```
function myFunc(parameters){
//код подпрограммы
}
```

function - ключевое слово
myFunc - имя функции
parameters - переменные, которые вы хотите передать в функцию в качестве параметров(скопировать их значения). Если несколько - разделяются запятыми. Если ноль - пустые скобки.

Вызов:

```
myFunc(someVar);
```